# How to fit image size to parent div available place

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with relative size.
inside the div I need to place some inputs, and below them an image.
The number of inputs is dynamic, so I don’t know in advanced the size it will take.
Is there any magic CSS styling, so the image size will fit the available place, without changing the parent div size?
I prefer no javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Yes this is possible. Please can you show your existing code so we can prompt you what to change?

Comment: style="width:100%" is a good start

Comment: Show us what you have done..If possible share a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with us.

Comment: Please review on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLmxy89L/) – the width:100% will not help with vertical image.
Also, I put a button on that fiddle that on click is append one more input - I need that whenever an input will be added the image will be resize to fit to the available height.